# Text in an android app with Java syntax highlighting

Tags: java, android, syntax, highlighting

Is it possible to use Java syntax highlighting inside of an app for android?
For example when you would add a bunch of code in a TextView. How would I color that in the Java Syntax highlighting? 
Or in other words is there a way to make the program do it for you or do you have to do all of it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Syntax Highlighting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: See this library https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641368/1770868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this.

[Android Syntax Highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting)

Looks like it might do what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think I can really use this in the XML files.

Comment: ah.  This might be a poor choice.....Sorry, didn't realize it was extending Swing.  This might not work.  My fault.  I'm just going to delete this answer to avoid future confusion.

Comment: try the link in the edit. Looks like you're not the first to go down this road.