# Using Java Prettify for Android app syntax highlighting

Tags: java, android, syntax, highlighting, prettify

I need to integrate syntax highlighting into my application for Android. I tried using Java Prettify(https://code.google.com/p/java-prettify) but I am failing to integrate it. The app is crashing. And since my avd isnt working, so I cannot get information from logcat about the crash.

I am following this info : https://code.google.com/p/java-prettify/wiki/UseTheParserAlone

My code till now :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import prettify.PrettifyParser;
import syntaxhighlight.ParseResult;
import syntaxhighlight.Parser;

public class PrettifyHighlighter {
Map<String, String> COLORS = buildColorsMap();
String FONT_PATTERN = "<font color=\"#%s\">%s</font>";
Parser parser = new PrettifyParser();

public String highlight(String fileExtension, String sourceCode) {
    StringBuilder highlighted = new StringBuilder();
    List<ParseResult> results = parser.parse(fileExtension, sourceCode);
    for(ParseResult result : results){
        String type = result.getStyleKeys().get(0);
        String content = sourceCode.substring(result.getOffset(), result.getOffset() + result.getLength());
        highlighted.append(String.format(FONT_PATTERN, getColor(type), content));
    }
    return highlighted.toString();
}

private String getColor(String type){
    return COLORS.containsKey(type) ? COLORS.get(type) : COLORS.get("pln");
}

private static Map<String, String> buildColorsMap() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("typ", "87cefa");
    map.put("kwd", "00ff00");
    map.put("lit", "ffff00");
    map.put("com", "999999");
    map.put("str", "ff4500");
    map.put("pun", "eeeeee");
    map.put("pln", "ffffff");
    return map;
}
```

}

While debugging, I found out that when I commented the line :
    Parser parser = new PrettifyParser();

and it's related lines, there was no crashing of app.
I googled but failed to get a solution.

My logcat :

```
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): Process: com.himanshujaju.codeit, PID: 1245
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: prettify.PrettifyParser
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.himanshujaju.codeit.PrettifyHighlighter.<init>(PrettifyHighlighter.java:14)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.himanshujaju.codeit.codeArea$Run.onPostExecute(codeArea.java:193)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.himanshujaju.codeit.codeArea$Run.onPostExecute(codeArea.java:1)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-02 07:57:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's a java library, there are some classes don't exist on android (for example: swing.*). You can try one https://code.google.com/p/android-codepad/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19787125/1340797 ... This is where I had seen this method for highlighting.

Comment: please post your `logcat` to find the reason.

Comment: I posted in my question that avd isnt starting. It is stuck at the android loading screen forever. And it isnt recognizing my micromax a116i too.

Comment: avd is very slow, you need to wait it start(create avd with small screen maybe better).If you use device, make sure driver has installed. Please google how to do it. Without logcat, I can't help you.

Comment: added logcat! Help now.

Comment: How can I add this PrettifyHighlighter into my android project

Comment: @R4j how can I add `android-codepad` to android studio ? the link you got doesn't any thing for download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked well.

```
  PrettifyHighlighter highlighter = new PrettifyHighlighter();
  String code = "for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){System.out.println(i);}";
  String highlighted = highlighter.highlight("java", code);
  textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(highlighted));
```

Here is the output Textview on emulator

[image: highlight]

For the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception, look like eclipse doesn't export jar library when it builds. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702315/719212).

Comment: Sorry too late to comment over this question but it gives strings as output.. In other words it does not intent the code... Is there any way it can retain the indentations