# Android Studio as source code editor?

Tags: android, mobile

So I have been programming for about a year now. All of my experience has come from school work/projects and I have an interest in Android mobile development/application so I would like to start using Android Studio to get comfortable before starting on a side project this winter break. I currently use Sublime Text, which I like a lot, but I would like to know if it's possible and worth using Android Studio as a source code editor (only so I can get comfortable using it).

Comment: You can use this library https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641368/1770868

Answer (score 1):

An IDE like Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) provides many tools that make programming, testing, managing & deploying much easier. Built-in Terminals, TODO list, Logcat are some of these. When your programming project gets bigger, it's much helpful to use a proper IDE in order to manage your code than a text editor. However, as a fact, Android Studio consumes lots of resources in your computer compared to Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android studio, it helps for prediction a lot. But  as it consumes more RAM, the chance for it to get stuck is high. So use Sublime when android studio gets stuck. I think it is the best practice. And i am following this method.