# Multiline Text code highlighter for android

Tags: android, html-editor, codehighlighter

I need library that highlight **HTML**, **CSS** and **JavaScript** code. And also User can edit the code.

Comment: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: I haven't found the library

Comment: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/tree/master/library

Comment: That's not what I want. Thnx anyway

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be hard to implement, but here is a recipe to make it.

1. To highlight codes in various styles, you can use https://github.com/binaryfork/Spanny work. It is appliable to `TextView` or `EditText`, as the result of Spanny is a `Spannable` object.
2. And, to analyze a text file as a HTML, CSS, JavaScript code semantic, you can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and iterate each element in order to highlight them with styles. One example usage of Jsoup in Android is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941653/361100).
3. Above two will show you highlighted output, but not editable as you type. One definite thing to do is to use `EditText.addTextChangedListener` event handler. Rest of editing and displaying fine `Spannable` result can be found from *EditText with Emoticons* trials.