# How can show c and c++ code in android using textview with syntax highlighting?

Tags: android, android-studio, syntax-highlighting

I am new to android programming.

I want to create a android app to display some c++ code.

How can I add my c++ source code to a TextView and display it with syntaxt highlighting?

I did some search in google and found this in 
[Android Syntax Highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting) 
but I don't know how to add javapreetify file to android studio(1.5.1) build path.

Someone please help me.

or make a tutorial please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd comment on your post but I don't have enough reputation yet...

There is some good information on this post here: [Android Syntax Highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting), specifically this comment which has an exmaple for integrating Java Prettify with a TextView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19787125/6786

Adding the JAR to the build file could be accomplished with these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/6786

Answer (score 0):

select the text widgets -> go to properties ->
put your c code in text