# Format/Indent Java code in an Android App

Tags: java, android, string-formatting, indentation, text-editor

I have to show Java code snippets into my Android APP. What I want: Save te snippet in database in plain String format. Like:

```
"public class Whatever {public static void main(String[] args) {new Whatever().print(3);}void print (int x){  System.out.println(x); }}"
```

---

After I import the snippet from database I have to show it on Android screen well-formated/indented, like here in StackOverflow:

```
public class Whatever {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Whatever().print(3);
    }

    void print (int x){
        System.out.println(x);
    }    
}
```

Is there a way to do it in Android without create/implement my own Java Code Formatter algorithm?

---

EDIT

Some more information:

I need only format the code. I don't want a syntax highlighting because I need something that is not dependent of code editor. So I will retrieve the code from database and apply the format and it will run in any simply text editor.

I looked through other questions, but most of then requires to embed some external code or requires some container, like Swing (java-prettify), WebKit (android-codepad, etc). Eclipse have a [code formatter](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fformatter%2FCodeFormatter.html), but It depends on a "TextEdit" component. But I will test it and try to extract plain text from it.

I cannot store the source code formatted with spaces/tabs, because most of time I will not touch the code.

I need that it recognize java 8 code blocks.

---

EDIT

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468122/java-library-for-code-beautify-format/3468875#3468875) are some other options I will try as suggest in the answeres. But most are outdated.

---

[This](http://www.newforms-tech.com/products/jindent/components/open-api) is exactly what I need, but I need free :\

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: I want more a code formatter/indenter than a syntax highlighting as the question you pointed asks.

Comment: The doc for the library suggests that it's a "pretty printer" which normally implies that it will format the code as well.

Comment: try this ansewer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19787125/5235032

Comment: @DougStevenson It's not the same. I need a standalone solution that I pass the unformatted code and receives a String with the formated code, without an external container/editor.

Comment: Why not saving it well formatted (with tabs and new lines) ?

Comment: @Enissay will not save the most of source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3468875/1811771). There are some discussions about the libraries which serve the need you want.

Comment: Link is dead!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use **escape codes** to save the code into the database. There is **no API** in Java that will automatically format the application code into a string and print it  to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Using Eclipse code formatter it's possible with below url have the example and api using which you are able to do this.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_codeformatter.htm

Comment: You can share your doubts related to this POst.