# Android TextView SyntaxHighlighting

Tags: android, textview, syntax-highlighting, prettify

I know that the title is a duplicated question but I have no other choices as some threads here in StackOverflow are old. Anyway my question is, is there a code for android to highlight syntax? I've tried using Java Prettify and created a code a based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19787125) but problem is some keywords are not being displayed and worst the code snippet are being displayed in a single line. I can't structure their appearance as a code. Thanks in advance.

See image example:
[image]

This should be how my code looks like but they don't have a highlighter like the above one.
[image]