# Android syntax highlighting using Java prettify, not showing (less than) < or <= sign in textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, syntax-highlighting, prettify

I am using java [Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/java-prettify/) for syntax highlighting of java code in android app. I followed this example
[Android Syntax Highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting/19787125#19787125)

```
public class PrettifyHighlighter {
    private static final Map<String, String> COLORS = buildColorsMap();

    private static final String FONT_PATTERN = "<font color=\"#%s\">%s</font>";

    private final Parser parser = new PrettifyParser();

    public String highlight(String fileExtension, String sourceCode) {
        StringBuilder highlighted = new StringBuilder();
        List<ParseResult> results = parser.parse(fileExtension, sourceCode);
        for(ParseResult result : results){
            String type = result.getStyleKeys().get(0);
            String content = sourceCode.substring(result.getOffset(), result.getOffset() + result.getLength());
            highlighted.append(String.format(FONT_PATTERN, getColor(type), content));
        }
        return highlighted.toString();
    }

    private String getColor(String type){
        return COLORS.containsKey(type) ? COLORS.get(type) : COLORS.get("pln");
    }

    private static Map<String, String> buildColorsMap() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("typ", "000000"); // black
        map.put("kwd", "760098"); // violet
        map.put("lit", "001ab7"); // dark blue
        map.put("com", "999999"); // grey, comments
        map.put("str", "ff4500"); // dark orange
        map.put("pun", "333333"); // 90% black
        map.put("pln", "156f15"); // dark green
        return map;
    }
}
```

and using it in the textview as

```
        PrettifyHighlighter highlighter = new PrettifyHighlighter();
        String code="public class Example {  \n" +
                "public static void main(String args[]) {  \n" +
                "    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){  \n" +
                "        if(i==3){  \n" +
                "            break;  \n" +
                "        }  \n" +
                "        System.out.println(i);  \n" +
                "    }  \n" +
                "}  \n" +
                "}  ";
        String highlighted = highlighter.highlight("java", code);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(highlighted.replace("\n","<br/>"),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivImage3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivImage3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivImage3"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/program_margin_top"
    android:background="@drawable/textlines"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="" />
```

OUTPUT: [image]

as you can see <= is missing from the output, it is just showing **i5 instead of i<=5**

**What is the reason that < is not shown in the textview, how can I display < in the syntax highlighted texview?** 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: replace the  ``<`` with a ``&lt;`` just as you replace ``\n`` with ``<br />``. Since this involves html, the ``<`` is regarded as an opening tag.

Comment: I was able to display <= by using highlighted= highlighted.replace("<=","&lt;=");
but when I try to replace < with &lt; it spits out this output https://ibb.co/gPsfSa

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
&lt; for <

&gt; for >

&amp; for &
```

Hope this will help out to display the escape characters in an XML file.

Comment: > and & are working fine without escape characters, but replacing < with &lt; changes output to https://ibb.co/gPsfSa

Comment: it displays &lt; in textView, instead of <

Comment: can you try https://unicode-table.com/en like 
 I used in https://pastebin.com/WKQWsTNQ

Comment: still not working, https://ibb.co/ft2rYF , also tried using html code &#60; no luck

Comment: I was able to display < in textview by using <. in code and replace it with &lt;             highlighted= highlighted.replace("<.","&lt;"); so thanks :)